# JSONObject is returning NULL Object

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, retrofit

I'm trying to draw a Route Between A Box Image and the current Location on the Google map
I could diplay the Box image and the Current Location Icon [image: Like this Picture] but when I need to draw A route between them the App crash.

My Code:

```
        private void drawRoute(LatLng yourLocation, String address) {

        mService.getGeoCode(address).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                        
                        String lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                                .getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location")
                                .get("lat").toString();
                        String lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                                .getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location")
                                .get("lng").toString();
                        LatLng orderLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng));

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.box);
                        bitmap = Common.scaleBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70);

                        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                                .title("Order of" + Common.currentRequest.getPhone())
                                .position(orderLocation);
                        mMap.addMarker(marker);

                        //draw route
                        mService.getDirections(yourLocation.latitude + "," + yourLocation.longitude,
                                orderLocation.latitude + "," + orderLocation.longitude)
                                .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                                        new ParserTask().execute(response.body().toString());
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                                    }
                                });
                    
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

It Crash I think because it says that responses.body().toString() returns NULL.I Search A lot for A solution but didn't know how to solve this issue.

The ERROR:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ymmyserver, PID: 32071
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object retrofit2.Response.body()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.ymmyserver.TrackingOrder$1.onResponse(TrackingOrder.java:139)
```

The whole code on Github TrackingOrder Class:

https://github.com/zieadshabkalieh/YmmyApp/blob/main/TrackingOrder.java

I'm using this api:

package com.example.ymmyserver.Remote;

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface IGeoCoordinates {
    @GET("maps/api/geocode/json")
    Call<String> getGeoCode(@Query("address") String address);

    @GET("maps/api/directions/json")
    Call<String> getDirections(@Query("origin") String origin, @Query("destination") String destination);
}
```

I think maybe the problem is that I'm using http not https maybe what's the solutuon?

Answer (score 2):

The error actually is that you can’t invoke `body()` on a NULL object, meaning your `responses` variable itself is NULL. Which is because you have a typo in there, your parameter is called `response`, while you are trying to access `responses` (mind the plural 's' at the end).

Comment: Or is this  in the question only? Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I clear the "s"of responeses but still the same problem I'm still debugging my code to catch why the response.body() is NULL..

Comment: according to your question, *not* `response.body()` was `null` **BUT** `responses` was. If you removed the "s", please pay close attention to the error message: Did it change somehow? If so, please update your question accordingly (or post a new one). Regarding any *why*, as @IlanP said, we can't tell you, you have to follow the chain.

Answer (score 2):

Janik is correct, the error stems from you trying to access a property on an object that doesn't exist (NULL); I recommend play process of elimination by first debugging your API call, log the response (toString) to make sure first you are getting data, and that data does contain a body; follow up with the next part and so forth; sounds like the issue isn't with the JSONObject method but that the data you're consuming returns nothing (either nothing, or a different response than what you expect); debug it top to bottom you'll find the reason.

Comment: Thank you Ilan P you are correct about explaining the error but I'm asking about why the response.body() is returning NULL.

Comment: Troubleshoot your API call in Postman, I can’t tell you why it’s null, you need to work down the chain